# Join a single column from another model in one dimension

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to have a single dimension result for datatables.net.

Say I have these 2 Models :

**CustomerModel**

```
class CustomerModel extends \sys\Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'Customer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'customerId';

    protected $hidden   = [];
    protected $guarded  = [ 'customerId' ];


    public function paymentMethod(){
        return $this->hasOne('\app\model\PaymentMethodModel' , 'paymentMethodId' , 'paymentMethodId');
    }


    protected $fillable =
    [
       'customerName', 'address'
    ];          

}
```

**PaymentMethodModel**

```
class PaymentMethodModel extends \sys\Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'PaymentMethod';
    protected $primaryKey = 'paymentMethodId';

    protected $hidden   = [];
    protected $guarded  = [ 'paymentMethodId' ];
    protected $fillable =
    [
       'paymentMethodName'
    ];          


}
```

If I select using CustomerModel like `AgentModel::with(['paymentMethod']);`
I would get:

```
{
    "customerID": 1,
    "customerName": "John Doe"
    "address": "London"
    "payment_method": 
     {
         "paymentMethodId": 1,
         "paymentMethodName" : "Cash"
     }     
}
```

What I want to achieve is I want to have `paymentMethodName` into the result as a flat object
like this:

```
{
    "customerID": 1,
    "customerName": "John Doe"
    "address": "London"
    "paymentMethodName" : "Cash"  
}
```

Hot to achieve that the "Laravel" way, without playing with raw query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Laravel API resources is a good use case, it transforms Models into Api responses, read the doc here [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources).

It is quite simple, start by building your resource, call it customer resource. This will transform your model into a JSON Response. This is also usefull if you creating a wrapper for some legacy code, then you can easily transform model into a new structure.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CustomerResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'customerID' => $request->customerId,
            'customerName' => $request->customerName,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'paymentMethodName' => $request->paymentMethod->paymentMethodName,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in your API controller code, you can utilize the API resource like so.

```
return new CustomerResource($customerModel);
```

This seems like a lot a work for very little, but this is a solution that helps you a lot when things get complex. When you are dealing with multiple models, relationships or similar. This is the preferred way, if people are interested Fractal is a nice alternative to this, as it was a popular choice before API resources was made [Fractal Documentation](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/).